# python 3: string to hex, hex to format

Tags: python-3.x, hex

Question: I need to convert a string into hex and then format the hex output.

```
tmp = b"test"
test = binascii.hexlify(tmp)
print(test)
```

output: b'74657374'

---

I want to format this hex output to look like this: 74:65:73:74

I have hit a road block and not sure where to start. I did think of converting the output to a string again and then trying to format it but there must be an easier way.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

==========

OS: Windows 7

```
tmp = "test"
hex = str(binascii.hexlify(tmp), 'ascii')
print(hex)

formatted_hex = ':'.join(hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2))
print(formatted_hex
```

[Error]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pkg\scripts\Hex\hex.py", line 24, in 
    hex = str(binascii.hexlify(tmp), 'ascii')
 TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

This code only works when using tmp = b'test' I need be able use tmp = importString in fashion as I'm passing another value to it from a file order for my snippet to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
hex = str(binascii.hexlify(tmp), 'ascii')
formatted_hex = ':'.join(hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2))
```

This makes use of the `step` argument to `range()` which specifies that instead of giving every integer in the range, it should only give every 2nd integer (for `step=2`).

---

```
>>> tmp = "test"
>>> import binascii
>>> hex = str(binascii.hexlify(tmp), 'ascii')
>>> formatted_hex = ':'.join(hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2))
>>> formatted_hex
'74:65:73:74'
```

Comment: I;m using windows 7 and I get this error ysing your answer: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pkg\scripts\py3\hex.py", line 31, in <module>
    formatted_hex = ':'.join(hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a `str()` call.

Comment: No problem, you have saved me a mountain of cycles stumbling in the dark. :) Thank you.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 I was getting: TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given), change it to hex = sbinascii.hexlify(tmp) and worked

Comment: @onxx You can convert a string to bytes via the `bytes()` type constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, islice
>>> t = b"test".encode('hex')
>>> ':'.join(x[0]+x[1] for x in izip_longest(islice(t,0,None,2),islice(t,1,None,2)))
'74:65:73:74'
```

Comment: That's great but please read the question. 'encode' doesn't work in python 3

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.8, this functionality is available in the standard library: [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) has a new parameter `sep`.

```
test = binascii.hexlify(tmp, b':')
```

If you want a text (`str`) string rather than a `bytes` string:

```
test = binascii.hexlify(tmp, b':').decode('ascii')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the expected output:

```
tmp='test'

l=[hex(ord(_))[2:] for _ in tmp]

print(*l,sep=':')
```

-->74:65:73:74